# Any simple way to count in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my code:

```
        Company.count({}, function(err, company) {
            Checkpoint.count({}, function(err, checkpoint) {
                Guard.count({}, function(err, guard) {
                    Device.count({}, function(err, device) {
                        res.json({
                            "success": true,
                            "count": {
                                "company": company,
                                "checkpoint": checkpoint,
                                "guard": guard,
                                "device": device
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

Is this the best way? or is there something that is more efficient or better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use **Promises**

Do it this way to make the query faster, efficient and more readable:

```
var countObj = {};
var countPromises = [
  Company.countDocuments({}).exec().then(count => countObj.company=count),
  Checkpoint.countDocuments({}).exec().then(count => countObj.checkpoint=count),
  Guard.countDocuments({}).exec().then(count => countObj.guard=count),
  Device.countDocuments({}).exec().then(count => countObj.device=count)
];

return Promise.all(countPromises)
  .then(() => res.json({
       "success": true,
       "count": countObj
  })
```

Also, please note the following key points:

1. Use **countDocuments** instead of *count*. The *count()* method has
   been deprecated in the latest version of mongoose.
2. Using promises the way I have recommended will make your code faster as it will make queries in all the four collections simultaneously instead of waiting for one query to finish to run the other as it was previously when you were doing it the *nested callbacks* way.
3. Try to use Promises instead of callbacks as much as possible as it makes your code more readable and manageable.
4. collection.query() method always returns a query object and not a promise. You have to call the .exec() method to convert a query obj to an actual promise like this: collection.query().exec().

Answer (score 0):

```
    objects=[Company.Count({}),Checkpoint.Count({}),Guard.Count({}),Device.Count({})];
    response={};
    Promise.All(objects).then((values)=>{
    response=JSON.stringify({"success":true,"count":{"companies":values[0],"checkpoints":values[1],"guards":values[2],"devices"}}); 
   });
```

The way mongoose handles the count is fine just the way you have used but ,your overall code has a problem of call back hell so to simplify it you can use 
[Promise.All()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to promisify everythin in the order you want and then create a JSON out of it .